# How to merge jpg and png images using php?

Tags: php, php-gd

This is png image:

[image]

This is jpg image:

[image]

Both are same width and height.

Expected output:

[image]

Code that I am using:

```
<?php
header('content-type: image/jpeg');
if(isset($_GET['source'])){
$source = $_GET['source'] ;
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('png.png');
$watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);
$watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);

$image = imagecreatetruecolor($watermark_width,$watermark_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, 0, 0, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 100  );
imagepng($image);

}
?>
```

Current output:

[image]

Could you help me to get my expected output?

Comment: Try to replace `$image` and `$watermark`. And line with `imagecreatetruecolor` is unnecessary.

Comment: I have done. But, no luck of it.

Comment: `imagecopymerge($watermark, $image, ...)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable the alpha channel. To use the merge function and to keep the alpha channel, you can use the function published here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php#92787

Your code will look like this:

```
header('content-type: image/png');

   function imagecopymerge_alpha($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h, $pct){
        // creating a cut resource
        $cut = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w, $src_h);

        // copying relevant section from background to the cut resource
        imagecopy($cut, $dst_im, 0, 0, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_w, $src_h);
       
        // copying relevant section from watermark to the cut resource
        imagecopy($cut, $src_im, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);
       
        // insert cut resource to destination image
        imagecopymerge($dst_im, $cut, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h, $pct);
    }

    
$source ='b.jpg';
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('a.png');
$watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);
$watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);

$image = imagecreatetruecolor($watermark_width,$watermark_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

imagecopymerge_alpha($image, $watermark, 0, 0, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 100  );
imagepng($image);
```

Otherwise the alpha channel is filled with a color and your background gets completely filled.

Be careful: You also mix up content-type image/jpeg and the output function imagepng. (I've chosen image/png & imagepng in my solution.)

Comment: Getting same result enabling alpha channel.

Comment: Hm, can you also try to enable the alpha channel for your final image? I'm not sure if its applied by merging.

Comment: Applied, but no luck.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I'll have a further look at this, give me some minutes.

Comment: You have to use this, too: http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecopymerge.php#92787 I will update the code in my answer.